# Synchronize SQLite database across devices

Tags: windows, sqlite, windows-runtime, uwp, c++-cx

In order to build a connected experience, I need to synchronize my app's data store (SQLite database) across several devices. So far, the only solution I found was to [roam data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx), but that has two immediate drawbacks:

1. Storage is fairly limited in size.
2. Synchronization can only happen at the file level (vs. database row).

The latter is particularly bad, as it would mean that changes on different devices could potentially undo changes made on another device, instead of merging the modifications.

Q: Is there any facility built into the Windows Runtime, that allows databases to be synchronized at the row level across devices? I'm looking for a solution that works with Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile.

---

**Update:** Additional information<sup>1)</sup> on what I'm looking for, and what scenarios I'm trying to avoid. The following list is in no particular order:

- The closest match (in terms of functionality) for what I'm looking for is the [Azure Mobile App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/). It allows for server-side DB storage, with conflict resolution callbacks. If this framework were available for each end-user's cloud storage it'd make for a seamless connected experience.
- I'd like to avoid having to poll for DB changes made on another device. OneDrive supports [Webhook Notifications](https://dev.onedrive.com/webhooks/webhooks.htm), so this is not a real issue (assuming other cloud storage providers offer similar services).
- I'd like to avoid downloading the entire DB to calculate the delta against the local DB. This would require some sort of web-based service. So far my research has turned up nothing, so this is something I will probably have to live with.
- I'd like to get change notifications in a timely manner. In case I have to do all the synchronization across cloud storage of the underlying DB file, this would imply that the DB should be uploaded whenever it changes. This is problematic, especially on metered connections.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *This information was provided after [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38294251/1889329) was given. Keep this in mind when voting on it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in feature for this; either you have to try and make roaming storage work yourself, or you need to have a service-based approach where the truth is in the cloud and the clients sync deltas back and forth.

Note that you still have conflict resolution issues in this case if you support offline access with cached data, but at least the storage limitation will be gone. (In theory you have conflict resolution issues even without offline access, but that's highly unlikely in a single-user app).

**EDIT**

For completeness, I will mention the [Microsoft Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx) as an option to help with synchronization issues, but it is in "extended support" now and the official documentation doesn't mention UWP, so I don't know if it works or not.

Comment: That's disappointing. I believe that what I was asking for is a fairly common requirement for just about any app. I understand that conflict resolution is still my responsibility. I was just hoping for a framework that informs me about conflicts, and calls back to my app with the details to have it resolved. I would have hoped for OneDrive support, but it doesn't look like there is any. At least Webhook Notifications allow me to respond to cloud content changes. Still feels like a kludge to download an entire DB, just to find the local delta.

Comment: Yes, it is common but it is usually cloud-based. You could look into offerings like [Azure Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) to help with a server-side component. Amazon and others have similar offers if you want to shop around.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but wouldn't *Azure Mobile App Services* (and others) require, that the backing store is on the server, controlled by the app author/vendor? That makes it useful for collaboration, but fairly useless for a single user, that just wants his or her data to follow them around, regardless of the device they are using at any given time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your requests make sense for new feature suggestions in Windows. As it stands, you need a server resource. Imagine any single-user app with roaming data (especially cross-platform); they probably use a cloud data store.